# OnCLickListener for one Item in ListView Row

Tags: java, android, listview

I've got a ListView filled with multiple items per row. How do i set an OnCLickListener in getView() of the custon ArrayAdapter class for just one Item, not the whole row of the ListView?

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable final View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        currentLayout = getItem(position);
        myViewHolder= null;
    view = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        myViewHolder= new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(myViewHolder);
    }

    myViewHolder= (ViewHolder) view.getTag();


    myViewHolder.content.setText(currentLayout.getContent());
    myViewHolder.number.setText("1");




    return view;
}
```

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: just set OnclickListener on view inside getview()

Answer (score 1):

To clarify first, `view` which you inflate is the row layout. In order to set the on click listener on a child item, simply find that item by id and then set the listener:

```
//It can be any type of view that supports on click listener
//Using TextView as an example
//Don't forget to assign an id to the child in xml
TextView childView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.enter_child_id);

childView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Do something
                }
            });
```

To have a different listener for different rows, it is better to set the listener in the `onBindViewHolder` not `getView`. `getView` is simply used just to inflate the view and therefore will make all your listeners on all rows non-distinguishable. In that case you can extract view or child views directly from the `viewholder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
TextView childView = holder.childView;
childView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Do something
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: @Sarius are you setting the listener in onBindViewHolder?

Comment: oh, i did it in getview, not onbindviewholder. But i dont have an `onbindviewholder` class? cant overrride it? @SoroushA

Comment: @Sarius it is not a class. you should override it in your adapter. i updated the answer

Comment: Im doing all that stuff in the ArrayAdapter class and I am using a Listview, not a RecyclerView... Does that make a difference? Because i dont have the oportunity to override it... @SoroushA

Comment: @Sarius it would be tough with a simple arrayadapter. recyclerview has all those feature already and adding those to a listview with an adapter seems like reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable final View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
    currentLayout = getItem(position);
    myViewHolder= null;
view = convertView;

if (convertView == null) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    myViewHolder= new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(myViewHolder);
}

myViewHolder= (ViewHolder) view.getTag();


myViewHolder.content.setText(currentLayout.getContent());
myViewHolder.number.setText("1");

yourview.setonclickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            do your stuff here
        }
    });
return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I was using a LsitView instead of a RecyclerView. After fixing that issue and calling the onCLick in `onBindViewHolder`, everything went fine.